# Legal principles in refusing to pay advertised reward for return of lost item if it was returned without knowledge of the ad

Tags: contract-law, common-law, advertisements

Say person X lost his valuable item and advertised a reward for the return of it. Person Y, who knew X personally, found the item before reading the ad, and returned it to X, who just thanked Y for that.

Later Y read the ad and demanded the reward. X refused.

Contract Law teaches us that it was perfectly legal for X to refuse as there was no contract. **Which legal principles apply here?**

P.S. It was a question in a test, to which I answered that the principle was *past consideration* as Y returned the item before reading the ad and so without expecting any reward. However, the tutor did not give any credit for my answer and explained that "*X never agreed to pay Y anything. To accept an offer, you must be aware of it.*".

Comment: Why are you asking us - your tutor gave you the right answer

Comment: @DaleM The answer I got does not make good sense to me, so I would like to hear opinions from the community before discussing it with the tutor. Specifically, did not X actually agree to pay by virtue of advertising — to whoever returns the item? Then, Y actually _did_ become aware of the offer, though late. Does not _past consideration_ apply here?

Answer (score 4):

The formation of a contract occurs at the point where an offer is made and accepted by a person to whom it was made. The acceptance **must** be in reliance of the offer - if you don’t know the offer has been made you **cannot** accept it because you lack the intent to create a legal obligation.

The reward for the lost dog is the textbook example. A real example is [R v Clarke (1927) 40 CLR 227](http://netk.net.au/Contract/RvClarke.asp) in the High Court of Australia.

Comment: "_if you don’t know the offer has been made you cannot accept it_" But eventually you learn about the offer. Why can't you accept it at that point? Will it have been revoked by virtue of returning the item earlier?

Comment: Classic unilateral contract if the person returning the item *did* know about the offer, though.

Comment: @Greendrake because you have already paid the consideration that the contract requires (returning the dog) and past consideration is no consideration.

Comment: So is _past consideration_ (as opposed to lack of elements of contract) the ultimate legal principle that makes the case no contract? The main question was about the applicable principle rather than to explain what my tutor said.

Comment: No lock of consideration is the legal concept - you can’t return a lost dog that is not lost

Answer (score -3):

For an offer to be valid it must be communicated to the offeree.there's no contract here.x does not have to pay y

Comment: This is correct, though I suspect the downvotes come from the lack of elaboration.